# Node.js isolated network

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I'm new to Javascript and Node.js and I'm trying to understand if it is a fit for my project. The code that will be written has to be on isolated network, so no general internet access. From what I understand this is fine and you can just download the packages that are needed for the application. What I'm not sure on is if these packages only have to exist on the server where the site would hosted within the isolated network or if every computer that would access the site would need these packages locally as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Server as in a web server? Are you making an internal website?

Comment: Hey @rammaidy There is only server where you need to install those node package at once.

Comment: no users wont need to install npm packages to use your site. but if you use binary-based packages, sass, for example, you cant simply move node_modules around so at least one time your need internet access

Comment: Yes, it's an internal site on an isolated network. I was just trying to figure out if Node.js would fit/work before I spend too many hours learning it. Thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: Docker could come to the rescue here.